# Python psutil.wait raise timeout without good reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, containers

I'm facing a strange situation, I've searched on google without any good results.
I'm running a python script as a subprocess from a parent subprocess with `nohup` using `subprocess` package:

```
cmd = list()
cmd.append("nohup")
cmd.append(sys.executable)
cmd.append(os.path.abspath(script))
cmd.append(os.path.abspath(conf_path))
_env = os.environ.copy()
if env:
    _env.update({k: str(v) for k, v in env.items()})

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=_env, cwd=os.getcwd())
```

After some time the parent process exists and the subprocess (the one with the `nohup` continues to run).
After another minute or two the process with the `nohup` exits, and with obvious reasons, becomes a zombie.
When running it on local PC with python3.6 and ubuntu 18.04, I manage to run the following code and everything works like a charm:

```
   comp_process = psutil.Process(pid)
    if comp_process.status() == "zombie":
        comp_status_code = comp_process.wait(timeout=10)
```

As I said, everything works like a charm, The zombie process removed and I got the status code of the mentioned process.
But for some reason, when doing the SAME at docker container with the SAME python version and Ubuntu version, It fails after the timeout (Doesn't matter if its 10 seconds or 10 minutes)

The error:

> psutil.TimeoutExpired timeout after 60 seconds (pid=779)
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 84,
> in wait_pid
> retpid, status = waitcall()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 75,
> in waitcall
> return os.waitpid(pid, os.WNOHANG) ChildProcessError: [Errno 10] No child processes
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".py", line 41, in
> run
> comp_status_code = comp_process.wait(timeout=60)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psutil/**init**.py", line
> 1383, in wait
> return self._proc.wait(timeout)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line
> 1517, in wrapper
> return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line
> 1725, in wait
> return _psposix.wait_pid(self.pid, timeout, self._name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 96,
> in wait_pid
> delay = check_timeout(delay)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 68,
> in check_timeout
> raise TimeoutExpired(timeout, pid=pid, name=proc_name) psutil.TimeoutExpired: psutil.TimeoutExpired timeout after 60 seconds
> (pid=779)

Comment: Are these two script fragments the same script, or a different script?  Are there three processes (the uninterrupted Python script, `nohup`, and `script`); or does the parent _exit_ (vs "exist") at some point?  You tagged this with "docker", is there a possible difference that a second invocation is in a different pid namespace or is pid 1?

Comment: @DavidMaze Imagine that I call the first script with `Popen`, and whiting this process I'm running another process with `Popen` but the last `Popen` CMD is something like "nohup /bin/python3 /scripts/bla.py "/tmp/abc.txt"

Answer (score 0):

One possibility may be the lack of an `init` process to reap zombies. You can fix this by running with `docker run --init`, or using e.g. `tini`. See https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/